# Sidebar push menu, help me fix the jQuery issues

Tags: jquery, html, css

The menu I'm trying to copy is from the site: https://matchbook.com/

Problem: The problem appears when you Expand the menu and than Collapse it and than if you click the first link (horse/Tennis) it appears in the wrong place. I'm using margin-left and margin-right to move the div depending on the conditions. I have checked online for such menu but haven't found any.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sidebar Push Menu</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!--Sidebar-->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul id="NavSub1" style="padding-top: 60px;" class="sidebar-nav sub-menu">
                <li>Another Link</li>
                <li>Another Link</li>
                <li>Another Link</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="sidebar-nav sub-parent">
                <li style="background-color: #508a38;" class="item"><a href="#" id="menuToggle"><img id="flipSVG" style="width: 25px;" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-15/96/Arrow-Right2-512.png" /></a></li>
                <li id="NavLink1" class="item"><a href="#"><img id="NavLink1" style="width: 35px;" src="https://matchbook.com/assets/images/icons/icon-sport-svg/tennis.svg" /><b style="padding-right: 10px;" class="Hidden"> Tennis </b>▷</a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="#"><img style="width: 25px;" src="https://matchbook.com/assets/images/icons/icon-sport-svg/tennis.svg" /> <b class="Hidden"> Cricket </b> </a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="#"><img style="width: 25px;" src="http://www.codingforums.com/images/rugby-union.svg" /> <b class="Hidden"> Soccer </b></a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="#"><img style="width: 25px;" src="http://www.codingforums.com/images/tennis.svg" /> <b class="Hidden"> Rugby league  </b></a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="#"><img style="width: 25px;" src="http://www.codingforums.com/images/soccer.svg" /> <b class="Hidden"> Australian Rules </b></a></li>
                <li class="item"><a href="#"><img style="width: 25px;" src="http://www.codingforums.com/images/az-sport.svg" /> <b class="Hidden"> All Sports  </b></a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <!--Page Content-->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Where does it come from?</h1>
                        <p>
                            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
                            The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/NavScripts.js"></script>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#menuToggle").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#wrapper").toggleClass("menuExpanded");
                $(".Hidden").toggleClass("Show");
                if ($("#wrapper").hasClass("menuExpanded")) {
                    $('#flipSVG').attr('src', 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nav-and-menu/64/arrow_back_left_navigation_user_interface_ui-512.png');
                    $('#flipSVG').css('margin-left', '110px');
                    $("#NavSub1").toggleClass("menuMoveRight");
                } else {
                    $('#flipSVG').attr('src', 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-15/96/Arrow-Right2-512.png');
                    $('#flipSVG').css('margin-left', '0');
                }
            });
            /*******************/
            //$("#menuToggle").click(function (e) {
            //    e.preventDefault();

            //});
            /******************/
            $("#NavLink1").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#NavSub1").toggleClass("ToggleOpacity");
                $("#NavSub1").toggleClass("menuMoveLeft");
            });

        });
    </script>
    <style>
        /*Sidebar*/
        #sidebar-wrapper {
            z-index: 2;
            position: absolute;
            width: 70px;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #43444A;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        /*menu content*/
        #page-content-wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            padding: 15px;
            border: 5px solid green;
            margin-left: 45px;
        }
        /*Change the width of the sidebar to display it*/
        #wrapper.menuExpanded #sidebar-wrapper {
            width: 180px;
            transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
        }

        .item a {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .items a b {
            margin-left: 5px;
        }

        .Hidden {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .Show {
            visibility: visible;
        }

        .date {
            color: #fff;
        }

        #wrapper.menuExpanded #page-content-wrapper {
            padding-left: 130px;
        }
        /*Sidebar menu styling*/
        .sidebar-nav {
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }

            .sidebar-nav li {
                text-indent: 20px;
                line-height: 60px;
            }

                .sidebar-nav li a {
                    display: block;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #ddd;
                }

                    .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
                        background-color: #16A085;
                    }

        .sub-parent li {
            position: relative;
        }

        ul.sub-menu {
            position: fixed;
            background-color: #2B2F35;
            list-style: none;
            width: 180px;
            height: 100%;
            padding-left: 0;
            color: #fff;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all ease .2s;
        }

        .menuMoveLeft {
            margin-left: 70px !important;
        }

        .menuMoveRight {
            margin-left: 180px !important;
        }

        .ToggleOpacity {
            opacity: 1 !important;
        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that, in your conditional statement `if ($("#wrapper").hasClass("menuExpanded")) {...}`, you set up a possibility that you would toggle the class `MenuMoveRight` on `#NavSub`, but you do not remove or toggle that class anywhere else.

So you end up with the possibility of toggling it on but never toggling it back off. That is what is happening to you.

The answer is to remove `MenuMoveRight` from `#NavSub1` on the initial link click, then go into your condition where you possibly re-add it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menuToggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("menuExpanded");
        $(".Hidden").toggleClass("Show");
        $('#NavSub1').removeClass('menuMoveRight'); /* ADD THIS */

        if ($("#wrapper").hasClass("menuExpanded")) {
            $('#flipSVG').attr('src', 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nav-and-menu/64/arrow_back_left_navigation_user_interface_ui-512.png');
            $('#flipSVG').css('margin-left', '110px');
            $("#NavSub1").toggleClass("menuMoveRight");
        } else {
            $('#flipSVG').attr('src', 'https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrows-15/96/Arrow-Right2-512.png');
            $('#flipSVG').css('margin-left', '0');
        }

    });
    $("#NavLink1").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#NavSub1").toggleClass("ToggleOpacity");
        $("#NavSub1").toggleClass("menuMoveLeft");
    });

});
```